# How to make maven-failsafe-plugin running Arquillian functional tests aware of EJB line number in stacktrace

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, stack-trace, jboss-arquillian

I'm running functional tests with Arquillian which uses the complete WAR of a Java EE application including entities, EJB interfaces and implementations and webapp (JSF pages and backing beans) installed into the local Maven repository, i.e. the tests are pretty close to integration tests. Sometimes, I'm confronted with stacktraces like

```
SomeRuntimeException
    [more container related calls]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2060)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy331.ejbMethod(Unknown Source)
    at package.JSFManagedBeanClass.method(JSFManagedBeanClass.java:[line number])
```

when the JSF backingb bean `JSFManagedBeanClass` invokes `ejbMethod` of an EJB injected with `@EJB` into it, e.g. `someEJB.ejbMethod`.

I don't seem to figure out how to get the line number where the exception occured in the EJB which is represented by `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy[number].ejbMethod(Unknown Source)` in the stacktrace.

I tried to add

```
<debug>true</debug>
<debugLevel>lines,vars,source</debugLevel>
```

to the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration as well as to figure out whether there's an option in `maven-war-plugin` - the only thing that seem relevant is `warSourceIncludes`, but it depends on `warSourceDirectory` which can't be changed if the webapp content still ought to be included.

Adding

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>target/generated-sources</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

to the WAR POM causes `maven-checkstyle-plugin` to be executed for `target/generated-sources` and fail on the generated JPA metamodel which makes absolutely no sense.

The Arquillian `@Deployment` method:

```
@Deployment(testable = false)
public static Archive<?> createDeployment0() {
    WebArchive retValue = Maven.configureResolver().workOffline().resolve("[groupId]:[artifactId]:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
            .withoutTransitivity().asSingle(WebArchive.class);
    return retValue;
}
```

Please note that there's a lot of fixes online for simple JAR dependencies (as opposed to load a Java EE WAR in the failsafe plugin test runner) which are almost all fixed by adding the mentioned compiler configuration options or `-g` to `javac` in other contexts. The existing solutions don't involve `com.sun.proxy.Proxy` which might be special.

Comment: Is `JSFManagedBeanClass` an EJB? That seems to be the implication from your stack trace

Comment: @SteveC That wasn't well explained. No, `JSFManagedBeanClass` is a JSF backing bean which invokes the EJB method `ejbMethod` on an EJB reference which has been injected with `@EJB`. The class name of the EJB is replaced immediately with `Proxy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke an EJB method it always goes through a proxy. Typically this proxy is generated at runtime and it will not have line numbers because it has no source code.

What happens from there depends upon the implementation, which needs to arrange (at a minimum):

- transaction management;
- security;
- interceptor calls;
- exception management (RuntimeExceptions from your method emerge wrapped in EJBExceptions).

*around* your actual method call.

If your EJB code does not appear in the stack trace then that means something has gone wrong either before your method was called or after it was called.

If you showed the actual stack trace (including "Caused by ..") and actual exceptions we might be able to tell what is actually happening.

I can speculate that you're calling a Stateful EJB while that same EJB instance is in the middle of another call (from an earlier HTTP request), because I have seen this before. Stateful EJBs enforce single-threaded access so that you don't have synchronisation issues. So the second call is chucking a wobbly (sometimes known as throwing an exception).